# PHP Regular expression replace for url

Tags: php, regex

I need help to replace the last occurance of numeric uri string from my url:
For eg I have url strings as:

```
$url1 = "http://localhost/mystore/electronics/company/5-mobile/5";
$url2 = "http://localhost/mystore/electronics/company/5-mobile/21";
$url3 = "http://localhost/mystore/electronics/company/5-mobile";
```

from which I want to remove last occurance of "/5" or "/21" or any other number following the last forward slash with empty string and get only:

```
$url1_after_preg_replace = "http://localhost/mystore/electronics/company/5-mobile";
$url2_after_preg_replace = "http://localhost/mystore/electronics/company/5-mobile";
$url3_after_preg_replace = "http://localhost/mystore/electronics/company/5-mobile";
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not using preg replace but a simple way :

```
if(explode(dirname($url1),$url1)[1] != "/5-mobile") {
    $url1_after_preg_replace = dirname($url1);
}
```

Reference :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: thnks. it only solves my problem partially. i forgot to mention that the url can also be: 
"http://localhost/mystore/electronics/company/5-mobile" 
where the "/5" part may not be present at all.